# Flutter: StreamBuilder gets other firestore documents when updating a single document

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have a Stream like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rentsStream = FirebaseProfile().getRents(widget.portfolio.id);
  }

Widget _rentsStream() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: rentsStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Loader();
        if (snapshot.data == null) return const Loader();

        rents = snapshot.data!.docs;
        return _portfolioBuilder(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

The stream is declared outside in order to not rebuild the stream every time I change the state.

Here I get a list of rents. When I modify one of them, this one gets updated but the problem is that it comes with the rest of rents incrementing the documents reads monthly quota (and also I don't need to get again the non updated ones).

Also it triggers with some state changes inside the page I return from the `StreamBuilder`. Video: https://youtu.be/RPid3Jn_UYQ
Each rent card has this:

```
onTap: () {
          Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false)
              .updateCurrentRentIndex(widget.index);
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            '/rent',
            arguments: {
              'newRent': widget.rent,
              'portfolioId': widget.portfolioId
            },
          ).then((value) => calculateProfitsExpenses());
      }
```

Is possible to just get the one I updated? Otherwise I'd need to save them locally and update the rents based on what I changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform are you running this on? On native mobile, the Firestore caches documents by default and (while your code will get called with all documents) only the modified ones are actually read from the server. Let me repeat that: while your snapshot listener gets called with all documents in the query, many of those may be coming from the local cache and those won't cause charged reads on the server.

This [local persistence caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) is also available on Web, but there you have to explicitly enable it.

Comment: just mobile for now (testing on Android emulator)

Comment: I added a video of the issue

Comment: Nothing in the video shows that your document read counts are increasing by more than just the modified/new documents. Keep in mind: while your snapshot listener gets called with all documents in the query, many of those may be coming from the local cache and those won't cause charged reads on the server.

Comment: aah ok. I thought it was retrieving all of them back again and so, incrementing the reads. I guess the only difference then is to enable this persistence caching for web. What about the StreamBuilder triggering again with state changes? Is that normal?

Comment: When the stream fires a new event, the StreamBuilder rerenders with its current contents. If you want some more specific behavior, you'll want to look at managing your own state for the stream.

Comment: ok fair enough. Add please previous comment to your answer indicating this is part cached

Comment: coming back to "while your snapshot listener gets called with all documents in the query...", does it happen the same when we call .get()? I mean, if I call it twice getting same content am I incrementing 1 or 2 reads to the quota?

Comment: When you use `get()` you're explicitly telling the SDK to check for updates on the server, so you pay for those checks as the server has to read the documents for them.